# Start AJAX request immediately but ensure page has loaded before adding elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I have found that submitting an AJAX request during the `<head>` section of my webpage avoids a tiny flicker on page load (where AJAX loaded content is abruptly added on load). Understandably this still needs to be refined to improve visual appearance when AJAX request takes longer, but for the most part this will already be inside the visitors browser cache.

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    ...

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $.get('{{jsonDataUrl}}', function(data) {
        foo(data);
    });
    </script>
```

Whilst this seems to behave properly I am concerned that the AJAX response may get back before the page has finished loading. Conceptually I believe that something like the following would be needed:

```
$.get('{{jsonDataUrl}}', function(data) {
    // AJAX data received, wait until page has finished loading...
    var id = setInterval(function() {
        if (window.hasPageLoaded === true) {
            clearInterval(id);
            foo(data);
        }
    }, 0);
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    window.hasPageLoaded = true;
});
```

Is there a simpler way to ensure that the page has finished loading before executing `foo(data)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use promise:

```
var promise = $.get('{{jsonDataUrl}}');

$(function() {
    promise.done(function(data) {
        foo(data);
    });
});
```

From jquery doc:

> This allows you to assign multiple callbacks on a single request, and even to assign callbacks after the request may have completed. (If the request is already complete, the callback is fired immediately.)

Comment: Works like a charm! I will accept in 6 mins (cuz StackOverflow wont let me accept right away) thanks again!!